# Keycloak "Audit Admin Events" as Default for all Realms

Tags: events, keycloak, admin, audit

is it possible to set "Audit Admin Events" as default for all existing and new realms?

I know this page: [keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#auditing-admin-events)

We run keycloak as Docker-Container. A Environment variable would be nice :)

Regards, Andy